# Why is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Why is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[2]{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ "obvious"? My book states this as obvious, but then proves the opposite inclusion. I would have thought that $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3})$ would be the obvious inclusion as we can just multiply the generators, I don't see why what they have stated is obvious.

Comment: @ervx sorry ive edited

Comment: It seems you've just got mixed up with your inclusions somewhere. We know that $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt[3]3$ are elements of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]3)$. Therefore, so is their product. So $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2\sqrt[3]3)\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]3)$.

Comment: One can multiply the generators, which is why it is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Your extensions are of the form $\mathbf Q(a,b)$ and  $\mathbf Q(ab)$. Now the generator $ab$ of the second extension is obviously a member of the first. Hence the elements of the field it generates, which are rational  functions in $ab$, are *ipso facto* rational functions of the two variables $a$ and $b$. i.e. elements of the  field they generate.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3})$ is the smallest field containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt2\sqrt[3]3$.

By definition, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ is the smallest field containing all $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt2$ and$\sqrt[3]3$. Since it is a field it must also contain the product of $\sqrt2$  and $\sqrt[3]3$ which is $\sqrt2\sqrt[3]3$

Now $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ contains $\sqrt2\sqrt[3]3$. Recall $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3})$ is the smallest field containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt2\sqrt[3]3$.

We conclude...